# ActiveMQ cosumer connection differ from producer

Tags: activemq-classic, failover

The following is my ActiveMQ setup:

I have two AMQ broker which are configured with failover.
I have 40 producer but only on consumer.

Now the problem:
From time to time, one of the producer lost the connection to the master broker. The failover reacts and the producer gets a new connection to the slave which gets the messages. So far so good. But the consumer does not have the problem, he consumes still the messages from the master. He does not know, that the slave has also some messages.

How can i now solve the problem woth losing those messages thay are sent to the slave?

Thank in advance

Comment: what version of ActiveMQ are you using?  master/slave failover is no longer recommended or supported in active development.

Comment: I use version 5.10.0. The failover i use lok like -> failover:(tcp://host1:61616,tcp://host2:61616)?randomize=false

Comment: I would recommend you configure a [network of brokers](http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html). That way, your brokers will be connected as well, and it no longer matters which broker your producers and consumers connect to - the messages will get propagated across the network.

Comment: @krautmeyer can you add that as an answer? It's the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you configure a network of brokers. That way, your brokers will be connected as well, and it no longer matters which broker your producers and consumers connect to - the messages will get propagated across the network.

Comment: So, i configured a small network of two brokers as duplex connection. It seems to work very well right now. One question occured again: in the webconsole of broker A which hold the duplex connection to broker B, i can see the incoming messages, so thats fine. In the web console of broker B i cannot see any incoming messages. In the connection overview there is the connection to broker A as outbound shown. But if all messages should be propagate in the network, the messages has to be shown in the console of broker B, isn't?

Comment: How many producers does the console show for broker A and B, respectively? If you use the failover URL as you had defined it in your original post, they should all connect to A, so there wouldn't be any message on B. Only once A goes away will they reconnect and start using B.